# Extracting n Number of Words from Pandas Series

Tags: pandas, list, csv, list-comprehension, series

I have a pandas data frame with about 2000 rows I have to do some work on and I’m stuck on one column. The column consists of comma separated words. What I need to do is to trim these words so only the first 10 ones are kept and discard the rest.

What I have tried so far is to turn the series into a list, then split with a comma separator, extract the first ten items and then add back the comma. All with a bunch of for loops. My code is erratic and even this is giving me some trouble but I have learnt how to do this before. I was hoping for a more elegant solution using a lambda function or list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, where 'a' would be the name of your column:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x.split(",")[:10]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get a ''Series' object has no attribute 'split'" error code though.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a short example of how the data looks? If it's a pandas Series object you should be able to just slice it as you would a list.

Comment: It does work after all. Thank you so much. The error message I got was because was calling the column as dfW = df[['Words']] instead of dfW = df['Words']. An error that happened because I mixed 2 versions of the jupyter notebook I was working on and failed to reload properly. Thanks again.